# Flex 4 skins -- when to include Actionscript Styling Code?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, skinning, spark-skinning

When using Flash Builder to create a new component Skin based on an existing Skin, one has the option to include Actionscript styling code or not.  Wouldn't this code always be necessary?

Here is an example of two people, both of whom have skinned the spark Panel.

With styling code:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/19/repositioning-the-control-bar-on-a-spark-panel-container-in-flex-4/

Without styling code:

http://www.popamihai.com/2010/11/flex/skinning-flex-4-components-skinning-the-spark-panel-component/

But they both seem to run fine.  How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

The styling code still gets applied due to the fact that you're extending a class.

You should add the styling code when you intend to change it.

Comment: What class am I extending with a skin?  They are all extending "s:SparkSkin" I thought.  I *wish* it was extending the original spark skin....